# Can the ASP.NET Core model binder bind data from text items like span?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, model-binding

As much as I know, the model binder in ASP.NET Core is capable to bind values that are retrieved

- from form items (input fields, checkboxes, radiobuttons, hidden fields etc.)
- from the url
- from the querystring parameter

Is there any practical way for the model binder to retrieve data from any elements that are displayed as simple text without being forced to display them in a text box? Of course I could also store a copy of the desired value in a hidden field, but I'd prefere to have it only once for reasons of maintainability.

Comment: No. Forms only post back the name/value pairs of their successful form controls (inputs, textarea, select)

Comment: You can use JavaScript to copy the span's contents to a hidden field on submit. Or you can use `<input type="text" name="foo" class="textAsSpan" />` with special styling.